# Returning result of stored procedure,sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions

How to return the results of multiple aggregate functions using one stored procedure.I am trying to get the average, total, maximum and minimum value of one column using one stored procedure.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... things like stored procedure and aggregates are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Answer (score 1):

In your stored procedure issue the following SQL statement:

SELECT AVG(col1), SUM(col1), MAX(col1), MIN(col1)
FROM table1

Answer (score 0):

You can call multiple selects on the function results in your sp and you'll return a dataset with 4 tables. or, you can select the values into a table variable and return the table via a select statement. There are numerous ways to accomplish this.